# Setting up a gallery with Colorbox in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, colorbox

Still learning MVC3, EF and Razor and I am wondering if anyone has successfully used Colorbox to enhance a gallery with MVC3 and will be happy to give me a helping hand.  I have setup a gallery model, controller and view.  I have images saved in images folder in the Content folder.  I generate the thumbnails dynamically from the large image files.  I have colorbox javascripts and css and jquery all referenced in the Index view of the gallery.  When thumbnails  are clicked a blank black screen results. Any help will be appreciated.

The index View is as follows

```
@using CPS.Helpers;
@foreach (var item in Model)
{    
<a href="Content/Images/@item.GalleryFileLink" rel="gal"> @Html.Image("Content/Images/" +item.GalleryFileLink + "?width=130&height=98", item.GalleryText)</a>`
```

at the bottom of the view page I have this
    
    `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".gallery_module").colorbox({rel: 'gal' });
    });
    </script>`

I am using an Image helper which is as follows

```
public  static class MyHelper{
    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string altText)
    {
        var url = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", url.Content(src));
        builder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }}
```

The thumbnails show alright at the view page  but when a thumbnail is clicked a black  blank screen results

Comment: Any code you would like to show?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have added code.  What I want to know is does colorbox just work  with MVC without any tweaking?

Comment: @Diin Don't worry about special tweaking for colorbox to use with MVC, it is just some js and css...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class that you are using .gallery_module might confuse you. Rename it to **.pic** instead because you need to add it for the link to every picture. The 'rel' tag seems to be only for organizing different groups of pictures within the same page. I would suggest you to download the colorbox.zip file from [here](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/). Inside the zip there are all the examples shown on the website. Isolate exactly what you need and see what elements you need to add. You will need something like:

```
<a href="path to the pic" class="pic"><img src="your thumbnail"/></a>
```

To add the styles and the scripts the best way I've seen is:

```
//in the head section of your page, in your _Layout.cshtml
@RenderSection("styles", required: false)

//just before the closing </body> tag in your _Layout.cshtml
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Then in the page where you want your colorbox gallery put:

```
@section scripts{
    //I like using jquery from cdn, but you can also reference your local file
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </script>    
}

@section styles{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/colorbox.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

In this way you have the styles and scripts on the pages you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your css and javascript files references to _Layout page. Also make sure you have javascript files references in proper order.

Comment: thanks very much your suggestion also contributed to the final solution